# MySQL REPLACE INTO - Update specific changes

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's pretend that I have an e-commerce that tracks customers and give them a score based on their behaviour.

I want to create a table (scores) that register this score for each specific client and update the total score if is different and register the date of update.

```
id hash score update_date added_date
1  abc  3     2017-07-11  2017-07-10
2  def  1     2017-07-12  2017-07-11
3  ghi  10    2017-07-13  2017-07-12
4  jkl  7     2017-07-13  2017-07-12
```

I am managing to create a MYSQL statement in order to complete this task and only update an entry if the score is different from the previous one, also based on the client hash (not id).

Let's say that today, the second client (hash "def") changed the score from 1 to 15 and all other clients remain the same.

I tried the following SQL statement as example, but (don't know why) sometimes my updated_date is changing even if the score is the same, like in the first case (client hash "abc") where the scores still remains 3.

```
REPLACE INTO scores (id,hash,score,updated_date,added_date) SELECT id,"abc","3","2017-07-14",added_date) WHERE hash="abc" AND score<>"3"

REPLACE INTO scores (id,hash,score,updated_date,added_date) SELECT id,"def","15","2017-07-14",added_date) WHERE hash="def" AND score<>"1"
```

This is the result got:

```
id hash score update_date added_date
1  abc  3     2017-07-14  2017-07-10
2  def  15     2017-07-14  2017-07-11
3  ghi  10    2017-07-14  2017-07-12
4  jkl  7     2017-07-14  2017-07-12
```

This is the expected result:

```
id hash score update_date added_date
1  abc  3     2017-07-11  2017-07-10
2  def  15    2017-07-14  2017-07-11
3  ghi  10    2017-07-13  2017-07-12
4  jkl  7     2017-07-13  2017-07-12
```

Comment: Questions: 1) Is there a unique index on the `hash` column?  2) What is the source and meaning of the `total` column in your SQL?  3) Why are you using REPLACE INTO instead of UPDATE?

Comment: Hi, 1) yes, there is a unique index; 2) sry my mistake, "total" should be "score" instead; 3) I'm using because everyday I want to update my table with the new scores and I'd like to use REPLACE INTO to check if the client (hash) already exist to update it or insert a new row

Comment: You are explicitly Using the date `"2017-07-14"` in your query. That why it is getting updated. Try to use `If already exist` clause.